# How to autoscroll image by image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have about 9 images on the scrollView, i want to make it autoscrolling image by image(like first image scroll to second and ..till the last one). I did something like this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.0 target:self selector:@selector(scrolling) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)scrolling{

CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

if(currentOffset < 2236){

CGFloat newOffset = currentOffset + 172;


[UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:2.1];
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(newOffset,0.0) animated:YES];
[UIScrollView commitAnimations];

}
```

but it just scroll only one time (from first image to the second). what did i do wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set repeats to YES.  It's the last parameter.  Also, make sure the interval is not 0.  (the posted code shows .0)

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(scrolling)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
```